# converting nested xml file into a data frame in R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I need to convert and xml file to a data frame using the xml package in R. My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item id="Applications">
    <content>
      <name><![CDATA[IT Applications]></name>
    </content>
    <item id="Web">
      <content>
        <name><![CDATA[Web_IT]]></name>
      </content>
      <item id="1234">
        <content>
          <name><![CDATA[FrontEnd-1234]]></name>
        </content>
      </item>
      <item id="3456">
        <content>
          <name><![CDATA[BackEnd-3456]]></name>
        </content>
      </item>
    </item>
    <item id="Corp">
      <content>
        <name><![CDATA[Corporate]]></name>
      </content>
      <item id="56778">
        <content>
          <name><![CDATA[Exchage-56778]]></name>
        </content>
      </item>
   </item>
</root>
```

I need to turn thix sml into a data frame like this:

```
Web     Web_IT      1234    FrontEnd-1234
Web     Web_IT      3456    BackEnd-3456
Corp   Corpporate   56778   Exchange-56778
```

any ideas how I would do this? has anyone done something like this?

Comment: Gave you given `XML:::xmlToDataFrame` a go?

Comment: @Roman Lustrik, I looked at that. It does not seem to handle the nested xml file. It just takes all nodes and makes it a one dimensional data frame.

Comment: My guess is that you'll have to climb the outer node and do some post processing to get the desired result.